# Why am I getting an array out of bounds exception/no console output with cipher?

Tags: java, arrays, exception, encryption, multidimensional-array

I can't see a clear reason why I'm getting an Array out of Bounds at this line:

`matrix[row][col++] = plainText.charAt(i);`

Could anyone elucidate me here? I get the out of bounds exception when I replace this:

```
                cipherText = Arrays.deepToString(matrix);
```

with a sysout of the matrix. With the original code in place I simply get no console output.

Thanks for looking, I'm rather lost if that wasn't glaringly apparent.

```
import java.util.*;

public class RailFenceCypher {

    public String encrypt(String plainText, int key) {
        
        String cipherText = null;
        boolean check = false;

        // The 2d array to store the encrypted/decrypted text
        char[][] matrix = new char[key][plainText.length()];

        // Filling in the blank spaces in the array
        for (int i = 0; i < key; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < plainText.length(); j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = '\n';
            

            // Checking whether going up or down in the array, reversing if at top or bottom
            int row = 0;
            int col = 0;

            for (int k = 0; k < plainText.length(); k++) {
                if (row == 0 || row == key - 1) {
                    check = !check;
                }

                // entering the char into the row
                matrix[row][col++] = plainText.charAt(i);

                // finding the next row using check for direction
                if (check) {
                    row++;
                } else
                    row--;
            }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < key; j++) {
                for (int m = 0; m < matrix.length; m++) {
                    if (matrix[j][m] != '\n') {
                        cipherText = Arrays.deepToString(matrix);


                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return cipherText;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the values in row, col and i when that statement is executed?  Are the associated arrays large enough for the arrays?

Comment: Can you provide a sample invocation of method `encrypt`? In other words, sample values for the method parameters, `plainText` and `key`.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that `matrix.length()` returns the length of [m], so your last for loops runs over the end of the array.

You possibly wanted to use `plainText.length()` instead as you did in the two for loops above.

Comment: I changed that now, still got the Out of Bounds exception. I also changed the for loop variables to row and col rather than j and m.

Comment: @Abra Of course!

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  RailFenceCypher rf = new RailFenceCypher();
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter the text you would like to encrypt:");
  String plainText = in.nextLine();

  System.out.println("Enter the number of rails: ");
  int key = in.nextInt();

  rf.encrypt(plainText, key);

  in.close();
 }

I'm just using a short string as the plainText and 3 as the key.

Comment: @NormR My intention was to make the array specifically the size required for the key and text with: char[][] matrix = new char[key][plainText.length()];

Have I done this incorrectly?

Comment: You should execute the code line by line with a debugger and watch the variables. Then you will possibly see why it fails.